# Can TransformListener get the transformation of an indirect child

Tags: c++, ros-lunar, transform-listener, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a tf::TransformListener listener to get the transformation between two frame in my c++ program.
My tf Tree is as follow Parent -> Child1 ->Child2  .
I am using the following line to get the transformation between Parent  to Child1:

```
listener.lookupTransform(frame_parent, frame_child1, ros::Time(0), transform);
```

When I am displaying the /tf topic with rostopic echo /tf, I can see a transformation for Parent -> Child1 and a transformation from Child1 -> Child2.

My question is, can I get the transformation from Parent -> Child2 ?  Can the TransformListener return a combination  of transformations ?
I wrote something like this:

```
listener.lookupTransform(frame_parent, frame_child2, ros::Time(0), transform);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316877/can-transformlistener-get-the-transformation-of-an-indirect-child/) by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> can I get the transformation from Parent -> Child2 ? Can the TransformListener return a combination of transformations ?

In short: yes, it can.

In fact: you can lookup transforms from *any* frame in your tree to *any other* frame in the tree, both forward and inverse. Doesn't matter how many intermediate frames there are.

This is one of the things that makes TF such a useful library (if it couldn't, it would essentially be just a very convoluted transformation matrix hashmap).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antoineniotna](https://answers.ros.org/users/34023/antoineniotna/) on 2019-02-27**:
Simple and clear! Thank you